# Xamarin.iOS build error MSB4096: "ReferenceCopyLocalPaths" does not define a value for metadata "ResolvedFrom"

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

After updating Visual Studio 2017 (including Xamarin) I get an error on several Nuget packages like:

...\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Apple.Sdk.targets(29,5): error MSB4096: The item "....nuget\packages\HockeySDK.Xamarin\4.1.3\lib\Xamarin.iOS10\HockeySDK.dll" in item list "ReferenceCopyLocalPaths" does not define a value for metadata "ResolvedFrom". In order to use this metadata, either qualify it by specifying %(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.ResolvedFrom), or ensure that all items in this list define a value for this metadata.

The error only occurs when building for Xamarin.iOS. Building for Android works fine.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Updated to latest version of Xamarin on VS2015 and am experiencing the same error, but with Arc.Support.iOS.dll. No solution found yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix this for my own solution by modifying the Xamarin.Apple.Sdk.targets file located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin. I added the ReferenceCopyLocalPaths qualification to lines 31 and 35.

Line 31

`<FrameworkFile>$([System.String]::new('%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.ResolvedFrom)').StartsWith('$(FrameworkPathOverride)').ToString().ToLowerInvariant())</FrameworkFile>`

Line 35

`'%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.ResolvedFrom)' != 'ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades' And`

Comment: Any idea where this fie is for VS 2015? I cant seem to find a Xaarin.Apple.sdk.targets file =(

Comment: It is most likely a Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets or Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets file. The error list showed me the targets file where the error was taking place.

Comment: That helped me too, thanks. @Kyle, I found the file here: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\

Comment: I wonder if Xamarin ever will release a stable version without new showstoppers. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Under 2015, that file is in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin.

The final fix we'll ship is to add this right after line 23:

`<ResolvedFrom />`

So the item definition group looks like this:

`<ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths>
      <DestinationSubDirectory />
            <FrameworkFile />
            <ResolvedFrom />
    </ReferenceCopyLocalPaths>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>`